# Find immediate parent based on condition SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to find the immediate parent id based on the below condition:

| CustomerNum | ParentCustomerNum | IsPlatform |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | 0 | 1 |
| 253 | 132 | 0 |
| 2041 | 253 | 0 |
| 2132 | 253 | 0 |
| 521 | 132 | 0 |
| 551 | 132 | 0 |
| 594 | 132 | 1 |
| 5642 | 5434 | 1 |
| 5811 | 5434 | 1 |

Above is the sql table entries. I do have below condition to find the record.

1. find record based on CustomerNum, check if it has ParentCustomerNum greater then 0 and IsPlatform is 1.
2. find record based on CustomerNum, check if it has ParentCustomerNum is 0 and IsPlatform is 1.
3. find record based on CustomerNum where ParentCustomerNum is greater then 0 and IsPlatform is not 0, then find the parent record and check again if that record has ParentCustomerNum is greater then 0 and IsPlatform is not 0.

What I have tried:

I tried CTE but having no luck on that side.

Expected values/query:

1. CustomerNum 594 has ParentCustomerNum as 132 and IsPlatform 1 (true). So, My query will stop here because IsPlatform is true. and will return this record only.
2. If for the above record IsPlatform is 0 (false) then query will traverse for CustomerNum 132 and will check if it has ParentCustomer and IsPlatform as false. @siggemannen let me know is any part is not clear. Thank you.

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT CustomerId, ISSCustId, CustomerName, CustomerNum, IsPlatform, CustomerNum As TopParent 
    FROM [dbo].[VwCustomer]
    --WHERE ParentCustomerNum = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.CustomerId, T.ISSCustId, T.CustomerName, 
        T.CustomerNum, T.IsPlatform, cte.TopParent
    FROM [dbo].[VwCustomer] As T
    JOIN cte 
        ON T.ParentCustomerNum = cte.CustomerNum
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.CustomerNum = 253
ORDER BY TopParent DESC;
'''
```

Comment: I don't get that 1. 2. 3. ... Is it "if no entries match 1. try 2. and if no entries match 2. try 3." ??

Comment: @Fildor could you please check the section "Expected values/query" that is clearly mentioning the expected things.

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but why not create a new column in your example table and add a expected value there

Comment: _"that is clearly mentioning the expected things"_ No it's not. If it were, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: Because from your requirements "1 2. 3." I conclude you could at first filter for "IsPlatform" - none of them accepts "false (0)", so that alone could drastically reduce the result set for the following steps.

Comment: @Fildor Let me again explain here. 
1. CustomerNum 594 has ParentCustomerNum as 132 and IsPlatform flag true (i.e. 1) 
Here in above case, my query will check if a passing CustomerNum (here 594) has ParentCustomerNum greater then 0 (0 means top most parent) and IsPlatform flag true (i.e. 1). This means this is the record I am finding. 
2. Now assume, above CustomerNum 594 has ParentCustomerNum 132but IsPlatform false (i.e. 0) then query will check for the CustomerNum 132 and will check if that has ParentCustomerNum greater then 0 and IsPlatform true (i.e. 1).

Comment: Would using HierarchyID be an option for you? => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16 If not, I guess you'll need some sort of self-join ... probably will be expensive. Do you have numbers on probability? Out of 100 queries, how many would hit based on 1., how many on 2. and how many would completely miss?

Comment: No, HierarchyId is to specify the hierarchy level/depth of the record. But here I need to check depth with filters.

Comment: I am not sure about real data as we can't see it. But 5 to 6 level/depth data can be there. Here depth means Parent-Child relation. Probability can be 50-50.

Comment: ``WHERE cte.CustomerNum = 2041``  chain is  ``2041->253->132``. What is desired output? 2041? 253? 132?

Comment: Your query output for CustomerNum=253 is``(CustomerNum, IsPlatform, TopParent)
(253,0,253),(253,0,132)``. This is what you want?

Comment: @ValNik
What I need is as below
(CustNum,IsPlatform,Parent) (253,0,132), (132,0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know if i understand, you want to know the first parent CustomerNum that is a Platform?

```
CREATE FUNCTION ParentPlataform (@id int) RETURNS int AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultVar int 
    DECLARE @IsPlatform bit
    SET @IsPlatform = 0
    WHILE @IsPlatform = 0 BEGIN
        SELECT @ResultVar = c.CustomerNum,
               @id=c.ParentCustomerNum,
               @IsPlatform = c.IsPlatform 
        FROM VwCustomer c 
        WHERE c.CustomerNum  = @id
    END
    RETURN @ResultVar
END
GO

SELECT dbo.ParentPlataform(253)
```